# How to create a single file Vue component in ES6?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

What would be the steps to a single file Vue component in ES6 ?

Comment: check the Vue.js docs: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html

Answer (score 2):

The recommended way is to use the official templates.

Both [webpack-simple](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack-simple) and [webpack](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack) have already configured single file components (vue-loader) and ES6 (babel-loader) correctly.

If you're interested in the basic configuration, just take a look at https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack-simple/blob/master/template/webpack.config.js

Comment: This is correct. I set it up manually and would not recommend it. Use the Vue.js CLI to generate your scaffold.